# Passing a string with a function and always getting $null variable

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am using the following in the start of a function that is meant to query a computer for various wmi objects. If just get_volumes is ran alone it should use 127.0.0.1. It seems that when I run get_volumes without any string this it passes right on to the else segment. What is the proper or a better way to accomplish this?

```
PS> function get_volumes([string]$a){
if ($a -eq $null){
    write-host 'Using localhost'
    $a = '127.0.0.1'
    }else{ write-host 'Using' $a}
}

PS>get_volumes
Using
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$a` is an empty string and not `$null`. Try this instead:

```
function Get-Volumes([string]$IPAddress = '127.0.0.1'){
    Write-Host "Using $IPAddress"
}
```

Note that you can set a default value for when the user doesn't supply an argument for a parameter.

Comment: This worked great. I was unaware of the difference between empty and $null, as well as setting a default value in that manner. Thanks Keith!